# how can i build large mounts of global data to a specific section?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I have a c source file with lots of global variables, and i want to build a object file with these global Variables in a specific section. add `__attribute__((section("section-name")))` for each variable is a large work, except add one by one,how can i build these variables to a specific section?

Comment: Use sed? Use macros? It's hard to answer without seeing some of your source.

Comment: you must add what you try.

Comment: @naveengoyal Nonsense.

Comment: _Which_ compiler? `__attribute__` suggests GCC.

Comment: hi Anonymous, in my c source file i use macros to build a .o file with only global variables, then i use objcopy to make a bin file from .o file. this c file includes some head files that have some global variables i don't want to build. so i think maybe i could make my global data into a specific section and then use objcopy to separate them from other useless data.

Comment: hi  MSalters,i use  gcc

Answer (score 1):

You could make your global variables members of one or several global structs instead. You might also want to consider your design and whether you really need to have a large number of global variables. Finally ... consider what you're actually trying to achieve; you haven't provided a reason why they should all be in a specific section.

Comment: i want to build a bin file which will include all global variables in my c source file. but this c file includes some head files that have some global variables i don't want to build. so i think maybe i could make my global data into a specific section and then use objcopy to separate them from other useless data.

Comment: But *why* do you want to do that?

Comment: i just want build both object file and bin file with the same C source file, my C source file can get data either from bin file or get data from it's build-in global data...  if i want to change data later i can just build a new bin file, no need to build code.

Comment: @norman sounds like bad design to me. Files should have well-defined machine-independent formats, not just be a binary dump of the global variables of the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be `objcopy --rename-section` afterwards. Another option is a linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
  .YourSection { YourFile.c(COMMON) }
}
```